# Пункты меню не реагируют на нажатие

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Пункты меню, вынесенные в ActionBar работают, а те, что можно увидеть лишь при раскрытии меню не реагируют на нажатие. Если поменять значения в атрибутах *showAsAction* и *orderInCategory*, чтобы вынести элементы ***item3*** и ***settings*** в ActionBar, то они будут нормально работать, а остальные два нет.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//Обработчик для меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.item2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "222", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.item3:
            Toast.makeText(this, "333", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "444", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

В xml код такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:title="@string/menu_item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_emojiconfused_white"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
          android:orderInCategory="2"
          android:title="@string/menu_item2"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_osclass"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/item3"
          android:orderInCategory="3"
          android:title="@string/menu_item3"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: у меня такая же проблема... только с Rich Box алерт диалога

Comment: все у вас написано правильно. скорее всего андроид студио тупит

Comment: попробуйте перестроить проект.

Comment: Покажите как это крепится к `ActionBar`

Comment: Перестройка проекта не помогла.

Comment: @Barmaley Не понимаю что именно нужно отправить.